# VBA Excel code for message box to appear while running a repeating macro

Tags: vba, excel

**My Problem:** I need to add a warning message box when a cell value in the range B11:Q22 falls below the value defined by cell K5. But

I have 2 worksheets, sheet 1(”weight”) is the active sheet. Sheet 2(“Base Date”) is a hidden sheet

Basically the way my code works, is:

1. When the workbook is open, a message appears asking to enter the correct item number in cell B3 in sheet 1.
2. When cell B3 in sheet 1 changes, it calls a macro on module 1, which periodically:
   a.    Saves data as a pdf
   b.    Opens another excel file and saves key data from sheet 1 and closes that file
   c.    Adjust the scales of the chart found in sheet 1 based on data from B11:Q22

**Solution required:** 
I need the priority to be, begin autosaving as PDF when B3 is changed (module 1 macro), but still bring up a message box immediately if any cell value in the range B11:Q22 falls below the value defined by cell K5 and once user confirms the message, continue with module 1 macro, until next value in range falls below K5

sheet 1 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim strPath2 As String
Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then

response = MsgBox("Are You Sure this is the correct item number?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
  MsgBox ("Please input correct Item number")
 Exit Sub
End If



'define paths and filenames
 strPath2 = "Z:\Groups - Sunbeam\Operations\Production\Production Data\Trade    Weights\BIB\BIB Trade Weight Summary.xlsm"

'open file
Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)

wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:4").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

'close workbook 2
wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)

Sheets("Weight").Range("B9:Q22").ClearContents

Call Macro1
```

Module 1 code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim sht As Worksheet   ' Creates a variable to hold your Weight worksheet
Dim strPath2 As String
Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight")   ' Sets the reference
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base Data")   ' Sets the reference

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sht.Unprotect ("xxxx")


 'define paths and filenames
strPath2 = "Z:\Groups - Sunbeam\Operations\Production\Production Data\Trade     Weights\BIB\BIB Trade Weight Summary.xlsm"

    'open file
Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)

 'copy the raw average data values across to master excel file

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight").Range("B5").Copy
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").PasteSpecial    Paste:=xlPasteValues


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight").Range("I23").Copy
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight").Range("J23").Copy
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight").Range("K23").Copy
wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


'close workbook 2
wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)


sht1.Visible = xlSheetHidden
sht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Z:\Groups -  Sunbeam\Operations\Production\Production Data\Trade Weights\BIB\Records\" & sht.Range("B3").Text & " " & sht.Range("G3").Text   ' Remember to preceed Range with sht. to explicitly reference the range of your Weight worksheet


On Error Resume Next   ' Continue with next line of code if we encounter an error
Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=False
On Error GoTo 0   ' Resume error-trapping


nextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)   ' Adds 10 seconds to Now
Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=True
timerIsRunning = True


For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
  With objCht.Chart
           ' Value (Y) Axis
     With .Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = sht1.Range("R14").Value
        .MinimumScale = sht1.Range("P14").Value
        .MajorUnit = sht1.Range("T14").Value
       End With
     End With
     Next objCht

sht.Protect ("xxxx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ' Remember to enable alerts at the end of code
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Apologies, the other code is in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim strPath2 As String
Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook


Sheet1.Range("a1:af1").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True

Sheets("Weight").Range("B9:Q22").ClearContents

MsgBox ("Please enter the correct 'Item Number' and press 'Enter'")


End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)



On Error Resume Next   ' Continue with next line of code if we encounter an error
 Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=False
On Error GoTo 0   ' Resume error-trapping

End Sub
```

Comment: have to figure the sheet 1 code is not complete. it missed at least one `end if` which i don't know where to place.

Comment: Where is `nextTime` declared?

Comment: Sorry! I misread your question. :(